# spam concerns with valid answers being changed to spam

Tags: feature-request

During reviews, recently I have noticed that there a number of cases where edits have been made to valid answers to completely convert them to spam. Thankfully those edits have been made by users with privileges not sufficient to make the edit official without approval but is there anyway we can prevent this from happening (maybe increase the minimum rating to 100 or something to be able to make a text edit).

Here is an example of the edit made

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spammers will always try to find routes to get their spam posted, but that's why edits have to be approved by several users before getting applied - therefore the system works.

Stack Exchange also keep improving their spam detection and blocking algorithms so every spammer that tries and gets rejected just adds to the spam awareness tools to help prevent the spam again in future.

So if you see spam, flag it as spam (if the original post is spam) or reject the edit as being spam if it's just an edit and that'll help us out a stop spam in future. If a spam edit is approved, you can click the "edited (date)" link to see the revisions and rollback the last non-spam edit.